Realm / MongoDB Delete the linked object with SwiftUI
Good day
I have 2 classes as follows:
class AnimalModel: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted(originProperty: "animals") var group: LinkingObjects<AnimalGroup>
    @Persisted var animalId: String = "\(randomName())"
    @Persisted var ownerId : String = ""}

class AnimalGroup: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var animals = RealmSwift.List<AnimalModel>()
    @Persisted var ownerId : String
}

When i access a Button to delete an Animal :
        Button(action: {
            $animalGroup.animals.remove(at: animalIndex)
        }) { Image(systemName: "minus") }

This only deletes the linked portion af Animal to the animal Group but not the actual item from the DB.
I am looking for a solution to permanently remove the animal-object from the realm DB
Tried to delete with:
realm.write{
   $animalGroup.animal.remove(ID)
}

but that also didnt work

This code $animalGroup.animal.remove(ID) does not work because the animalGroup model does not have an animal property. I posted a solution of how to delete an object from the database directly.

You're observation is correct; that code removes the element from the List but does not affect the actual object stored in the database.
To remove the object entirely (which will also remove it from any List properties that reference it)
Assume we have an @ObservedResults of items and a @State var which contains the selected item in a SwiftUI List
@ObservedResults(Item.self) var items
@State var selectedItem: Item?

var body: some View {
    List(items, selection: $selectedItem) {
        ItemRow(item: $0) //a view that shows an item name
            .tag($0) //need this for macOS row selection to work
    }

Then a couple of different ways to delete the selected item object
Button(action: {
    if let maybeItem = selectedItem {
        let thawedItem = maybeItem.thaw()
        let thawedRealm = thawedItem?.realm!.thaw()
        try! thawedRealm?.write {
            thawedRealm?.delete(thawedItem!)
        }
        selectedItem = nil
    }
}, label: {
    Label("Remove Item", systemImage: "minus.circle")
})

or more simply
Button("Delete Item", role: .destructive) {
    $items.remove(selectedItem!)
}

The second option works because while Realm Results collections are immutable, the ObservedResults is a mutable collection and allows writes via a two-way binding. Writes are implicitly opened and the changes are saved.

Good day Thanks for the help, above does not work... please see updated brief

@CoenraadPrinsloo When you say does not work, what does that mean? That code was taken straight out of a fully working project so it does work in that context. Perhaps your implementation is different? I don't know what an updated brief is... can you clarify so I can take a look?
